# AWS Simple AD : SSH based key Authentication for Linux instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

We currently have openldap setup and we upload new user's keys to LDAP and they are able to login to our AWS EC2 Linux instances using these keys.

We are planning to migrating to AWS Simple AD, Does AWS Simple AD offer feature of uploading SSH keys for new users ? and authenticating to Linux servers using this uploaded SSH key? Sorry I couldnt find any definite answer on google, any direct help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can interact with SimpleAD in the same way you would with any ldapserver. You will need to be within the VPC but the following code works (assuming you already have the user `Test User` created in the directory

## Example

**/tmp/username.ldif**

```
dn: CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=org
changeType: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: ldapPublicKey

dn: CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=org
changeType: modify
add: sshPublicKey
sshPublicKey: ssh-rsa ....
```

`ldbmodify --verbose --url "ldap://ad.example.org" --user "SIMPLEAD_USERNAME" --password 'SIMPLE_AD_PASSWORD' /tmp/username.ldif`

This post details joining the realm and using it to auth the servers using sssd with `AuthorizedKeysCommand`.

https://github.com/localytics/chef-sssd/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md